Computation of force on iron rod with non-linear B-H curve when passing through a coil
I am using the finite element software FEMM to compute the force on an iron rod passing through a coil and get results that disagree with my understanding when the iron has a non-linear B-H curve and reaches saturation.
As a sanity check, I tested a core with $ \mu_r=1$ and got no force as I expected.
Core with linear B-H and constant relative permeability I get a force that increases quadratically with the current which makes sense to me.
For a core with non linear B-H curve I set $ \mu_r=2000$ up to a field strength of 2 Tesla, and to a value of  $ \mu_r=1$ above above 2 Tesla. Here I get that up to field strengths of about 2 Tesla the force increase quadratically with the current which is what I expected, while above 2 Tesla it continues to increase linearly with the current (pretty much indefinitely) while I expected the force to remain constant (i.e. the core to behave like air above 2 Tesla). Is my understanding correct? If so, what do I have to change to get these results by the program?
